# How to transfer data of ng-repeat items by clicking from one view to another view if both views have only one controller?

Tags: angularjs, indexing, controller, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two views(2 html templates) both have one common controller

now in view 1 which contains ng-repeat items

for example :

> In "view 1" : ng-repeat = "monthid in years"

it shows:
month 1,
month 2,
...
month 12

So now i want to click on "month 1" and send its value suppose its name like "january" to "view 2"

In view 2, there will be only one thing just month 1's name(january).
Like this,

If i click on "month 2" there will be only one thing just month 2's name (February) in view 2.

How to achieve this?

Comment: you can set the value in root scope variable on view 1 and get the value from the same root scope variable on view 2. Either you can create a factory to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see three solutions to share data between controllers:

- Store your variable in a service and inject your service in both controller.
- Use events (i.e `$broadcast`, `$on` methods) to notify controllers.
- Use scope inheritance and store your variable in a parent controller. This should be avoided most of the time since refactoring and unit tests may be hard.

In my opinion, the best way to share variables between two controllers is to use a service (simple, easy to test):

- Store the month in your service.
- Inject the service in both controller.

Here is an example:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .service('filterService', function() {
        var _year;
        this.getYear = function() {
            return _year;
        };

        this.setYear = function(year) {
            _year = year;
        };
    })

    .controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, filterService) {
        $scope.chooseYear = function(year) {
            filterService.setYear(year);
        };
    })

    .controller('Ctrl2', function($scope, filterService) {
        $scope.year = filterService.getYear();

        $scope.$watch(filterService.getYear, function(newValue) {
            $scope.year = newValue;
        });
    });
```

Note that if you can use `Object.defineProperty` method (available with IE >= 9), your controllers can be refactored to use `$scope.year` everywhere (and you can remove the call to the `$watch` mhttps://plnkr.co/edit/G2pVFMV5Z2yXYSCkgZYs?p=infoethod):

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .service('filterService', function() {
        var _year;
        this.getYear = function() {
            return _year;
        };

        this.setYear = function(year) {
            _year = year;
        };
    })

    .controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, filterService) {
        Object.defineProperty($scope, 'year', {
            get: filterService.getYear,
            set: filterService.setYear
        });
    })

    .controller('Ctrl2', function($scope, filterService) {
        Object.defineProperty($scope, 'year', {
            get: filterService.getYear,
            set: filterService.setYear
        });
    });
```

Here is a plunkr if you want to test : https://plnkr.co/edit/G2pVFMV5Z2yXYSCkgZYs?p=info